# Internal server error at CreateBucket "Valid field 'bucketKey' must be of the form [-_.a-z0-9]{3,128}"

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm applying the first tutorial in this link;

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/ (view your models section)

I’m getting an error while creating new bucket with .NET Framework Project. But I’m entering a valid bucket name such as “zaferbucket”.

Here’s the error :

Error calling CreateBucket: {\"reason\":\"Valid field 'bucketKey' must be of the form [-_.a-z0-9]{3,128}\"}

It's internal server error (500).

Comment: Did you put in any capitals or spaces? As the pattern in the error message indicates the bucket name must be all lower letters plus numbers and `-` and `_` allowed - if the problem persists can you post the code you are using to create the bucket for us to look into?

Comment: @BryanHuang , i'm entering all lowercase and no spaces or capitals,  my bucket name is "zaferbucket" . i works on nodejs project but doesn't work on .net framework project.  Codes are the same copied from the tutorial.

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bucketsmanager-desktop) tool to check for currently existing buckets on your machine. Are u sure your datamodel is correct and tranfsers between your front/back-end correctly ? cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've followed the sample [here](https://github.com/dukedhx/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/OSSController.cs#L95) and convert the ClientID to lower cases as well when the bucketKey is submitted to the service:

```
public string ClientId { get { return OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CLIENT_ID").ToLower(); } }
```

Post your code in full if the issue persists so we can look into the issue.